# Android app crashes when trying to read contacts in Android Marshmallow (Android M)

Tags: android, user-permissions

I have target my app to SDK version 23 (Android Marsmallow)

When I tried to read a contact from my application I got this exception, though I gave **READ_CONTACTS** permission in my Android manifest file.
I guess the simple try catch wouldn't be the proper handling.

**Exception details:**

> Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2 uri content://com.android.contacts/data from pid=8373, uid=10152 requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS, or grantUriPermission()

My manifest permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: paste ur manifest file

Comment: @Neha updated my manifest permissions.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f17qe9vZ8RM

Comment: i need ur full manifest file..hope u have not declared permission inside application tag

Comment: please check if u have <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> at the top of your manifest file and try adding permission of write external storage. Hope it works :)

Comment: @Neha I am sure, there won't be any mistakes in manifest. As it does work well if I target 21. Now I am testing my app with target 23 (Android M). Thats why I am getting this error.  Pretty sure about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is want I want.

http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en

Complete permission related solutions. Hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 10):

**Runtime Permissions**

If the permission you need to add isn't listed under the normal permissions, you'll need to deal with "Runtime Permissions". Runtime permissions are permissions that are requested as they are needed while the app is running. These permissions will show a dialog to the user, similar to the following one:

[image]

The first step when adding a "Runtime Permission" is to add it to the AndroidManifest:

```
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.codepath.androidpermissionsdemo" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

You'll need to initiate the permission request and handle the result. The following code shows how to do this in the context of an Activity, but this is also possible from within a Fragment.

```
    // MainActivity.java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // In an actual app, you'd want to request a permission when the user performs an action
        // that requires that permission.
        getPermissionToReadUserContacts();
    }

    // Identifier for the permission request
    private static final int READ_CONTACTS_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST = 1;

    // Called when the user is performing an action which requires the app to read the
    // user's contacts
    public void getPermissionToReadUserContacts() {
        // 1) Use the support library version ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(...) to avoid
        // checking the build version since Context.checkSelfPermission(...) is only available
        // in Marshmallow
        // 2) Always check for permission (even if permission has already been granted)
        // since the user can revoke permissions at any time through Settings
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // The permission is NOT already granted.
            // Check if the user has been asked about this permission already and denied
            // it. If so, we want to give more explanation about why the permission is needed.
            if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
                    Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)) {
                // Show our own UI to explain to the user why we need to read the contacts
                // before actually requesting the permission and showing the default UI
            }

            // Fire off an async request to actually get the permission
            // This will show the standard permission request dialog UI
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
                    READ_CONTACTS_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST);
        }
    }

    // Callback with the request from calling requestPermissions(...)
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           @NonNull String permissions[],
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        // Make sure it's our original READ_CONTACTS request
        if (requestCode == READ_CONTACTS_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST) {
            if (grantResults.length == 1 &&
                    grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Read Contacts permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Read Contacts permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
}
```

here the original post

https://guides.codepath.com/android/Understanding-App-Permissions

Comment: It would be helpful if you add original url from [codepath](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Understanding-App-Permissions).

Comment: @chancyWu  original url added.