# Android app crashes on 6.0 while seeking permissions with ActivityCompat.requestPermissions

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

I've following MainActivity which seeks permission for 6.0 Phone & Storage tasks. It prompts for
permission 2x times and then crashes. Do I need to re-start the MainActivity after I acquired_permission?
thanks for any help or pointers.

MainActivity.java

```
onCreate(){
seek_permissions()
//load db data and continue
//with the app tasks
}


public void seek_permissions(){
            boolean hasWritePermission = (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
            if (!hasWritePermission) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Manifest.permission.MOUNT_FORMAT_FILESYSTEMS,Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED,Manifest.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE}, REQUEST_PERM);
            }        
    }
     @Override public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_PERM:
            {
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                acquired_perm = 1;
                }
                else {Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please consider granting these permissions", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); }
            }
            return;
        } 
    }
```

Comment: "It prompts for permission 2x times and then crashes" -- please post the Java stack trace associated with the crash.

Comment: thanks for the response, will post it soon.

Comment: Same issue here, app works on 4.4 fine, it crashes in 6.0+

Comment: I'm away from 6.0 device right now, unable to gather the logs. @Talha, do you see any hints from crash logs ?

Comment: no logs, no exceptions, just app closes with message app stopped working, on debugging with break points I saw that app crashes at line `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE})`, I checked logs very carefully from verbose level, but nothing.

Comment: thanks for the details, let me google on this and get back with results

Comment: @talha, I made a mistake of not adding these permission to Manifest file. Is that same case with you too? Do you have these permission on Android Manifest? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32115650/android-app-crashes-when-trying-to-read-contacts-in-android-marshmallow-android

Comment: Looks like there is work-around setting android:targetSdkVersion="22" (not 23) will ensure app runs without runtime permission in M  too. I'll give it a try.

Comment: I have permissions in manifest. Now it works fine on the device, but I remember that I had declared permissions earlier, it should not be the issue.

Comment: Strange, above code works fine now? If so, can you post the manifest and code as answer. I'll check it out.

Answer (score 8):

For me this was caused by using `android:noHistory="true"` in my manifest for this activity?

I believe this may be a bug with Android 6.0 as later versions work fine it seems.

If `noHistory` is set the `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions` call causes the `onDestroy` of the calling Activity to be executed thus destroying. As it isn't saved in the history due to the `noHistory` it no longer exists and the app is essentially closed when permission dialogue is dismissed.

As a workaround instead of `"noHistory"` in the manifest you can call `finish()` in `onStop()` or another appropriate location when navigating away from the Activity and remove the  tag from your manifest.

Comment: @webminal.org I know it's old but can you mark this as correct as people still upvote this answer?