# Android "Unfortunately, MyApp Has Stopped"

Tags: android, android-studio

I get this error and the app crashes when i run the it on my device.

I'm using Android Studio 1.3.2.

This is my Stack Trace:

```
08-06 13:26:35.980    8874-8889/com.test.myapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: com.test.myapp, PID: 8874
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.contacts.SemcContactsProvider2 from ProcessRecord{c94f2c4 8874:com.test.myapp/u0a60} (pid=8874, uid=10060) requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS or android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS
            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1627)
            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1579)
            at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getContentProvider(ActivityManagerNative.java:3565)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:4878)
            at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContextImpl.java:2004)
            at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:1477)
            at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:481)
            at android.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:64)
            at android.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:42)
            at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader.onLoadInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:312)
            at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:69)
            at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:57)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: You have not given contact permission in Android Manifest

Comment: In future questions you might find it useful to include some code to show what you are trying to do, not just a stack trace. Only having a stack trace might not be enough for us to debug.
Also describe what you have tried already, so we can help more effectively.

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.contacts.SemcContactsProvider2 from ProcessRecord{c94f2c4 8874:com.test.myapp/u0a60} (pid=8874, uid=10060) requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS or android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS` You need to learn how to interpret the logcat.

Answer (score 0):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
```

Also write if you want to write a contact:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"/>
```

Put these lines into your manifest file (Directly inside the "manifest" tag)

Answer (score 0):

Add permission in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"/>
```

Android M+ needs runtime permission  [implement like this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32115650/android-app-crashes-when-trying-to-read-contacts-in-android-marshmallow-android)

Answer (score 0):

as the stack trace says, you need to ask for permissions.  `requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS or android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS`

put this in your manifes

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"/>
```

note that if you're building for android M+ you should also ask for permissions at runtime.